# Write integer to OPC UA server - “not of the same type” error

Tags: c#, node.js, wpf, opc-ua

I have defined an OPC UA Client

```
 var client = new OpcClient("opc.tcp://localhost:4840");
 client.Connect();
```

That works properly and connects to a server that I have also written.
Also the client can read

```
var status = client.WriteNode("ns=2;s=Temperature", 999);
```

The problem comes out when I want to write a value to the server:

```
var status = client.WriteNode("ns=2;s=Temperature", 999);
```

instead I get the error:

> "The value supplied for the attribute is not of the same type as the attribute's value."

[image]

That link
[Write Boolean to OPC UA server - "not of the same type" error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38522058/write-boolean-to-opc-ua-server-not-of-the-same-type-error)
didn't help.

I used the Opc.UaFx implementation.

Thanks in advance

Patrick

Comment: Your code sample for "read" contains yet another example for write

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add the keyword double:

```
var status = client.WriteNode("ns=2;s=Temperature", (double)999);
```